# Help with Benguiat fonts

Tags: fonts, installing-fonts

I have been looking for a Benguiat font for use with latex. I found one source that requires xelatex and seems to be only in one size. (Alas, I can't remember where I found it.) I also found fonts/psfonts/corelpak on ctan which claims to have Benquiat fonts, but I don't understand how install them correctly. The README is incomplete and presumes knowledge on the part of the user that I lack. corelpak is pretty old. I'm wondering if it is still in use and if anyone can offer advice on installation.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)

Comment: You can use any OpenType font with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX. They just get installed in your system fonts directory. So assuming you have the font (e.g. Linotype sells it: https://www.linotype.com/576/itc-benguiat-family.html) using it should not be difficult.

Comment: The `corelpak` stuff assumes you have the fonts from software distributed with Corel software, which I assume you don't have, so it won't help you at all.

Answer (score 2):

I doubt that Type 1 versions of this font are still sold, so you should use an OpenType version with `fontspec` in XeTeX or LuaTeX.

Several versions of Benguiat are sold, and how you should invoke `fontspec` depends on which digitization you license. For example, ITC’s Benguiat Pro offers many unusual discretionary ligatures and two stylistic sets, while Scriptorium’s Baldessare offers neither.

If you can’t or won’t pay for this commercial design, then, rather than turn to a dubious site offering pirated fonts, you should look for a truly free font with some similarity to Benguiat. [Identifont](http://www.identifont.com/) allows you to search by similarity, and its fourth suggestion for fonts like Benguiat is the free Amarante, from [Sorkin Type](http://sorkintype.com/) and [Google](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Amarante).

It’s not exactly like Benguiat, but it does resemble the condensed width Benguiat and has the same Art Nouveau inspiration:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Amarante-Regular.ttf}
\begin{document}
ABCDEFGHIJKLMN

OPQRSTUVWXYZ

abcdefghijklmn

opqrstuvwxyz

0123456789
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

If you want multiple widths and weights and italics, you’ll need to purchase a license for the real thing.

Answer (score 0):

A free Truetype version is available at www.fontpalace.com/font-download/Benguiat/ Since I do not have the Corel fonts, the Truetype version seems to work well enough with xelatex.